# for loop only showing result of one case in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I intend to fill a matrix I created that has 1000 rows and 2 columns. Here B is 1000.

```
resampled_ests <- matrix(NA, nrow = B, ncol = 2)
names(resampled_ests) <- c("Intercept_Est", "Slope_Est")
```

I want to fill it using a for loop looping from 1 to 1000.

```
ds <- diamonds[resampled_values[b,],]
```

Here, each of the ds(there should be 1000 versions of it in the for loop) is a data frame with 2 columns and 2000 rows. and I would like to use the `lm()` function to get the Beta coefficients of the two columns of data.

```
for (b in 1:B) {
#Write code that fills in the matrix resample_ests with coefficent estimates.
  ds <- diamonds[resampled_values[b,],]
  lm2 <- lm(ds$price~ds$carat, data = ds)
  rowx <- coefficients(lm2)
  resampled_ests <- rbind(rowx)
}
```

However, after I run the loop, `resampled_ests`, which is supposed to be a matrix of 1000 rows only shows 1 row, 1 pair of coefficients. But when I test the code outside of the loop by replacing b with numbers, I get different results which are correct. But by putting them together in a for loop, I don't seem to be row binding all of these different pairs of coefficients. Can someone explain why the result matrix `resampled_ets`is only showing one result case(1 row) of data?

Comment: Could you also include what the variables `B`, `resampled_values` and `b` are? Then this problem will be reproducible for others to help you.

Comment: Why not use the boot package?

Comment: The value assigned to the `re-sampled_values` keep changing every iteration. Maybe `resampled_ests <- rbind(resampled_ests , rowx)` or some other from to store the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rbind(x)` returns `x` because you're not binding it to anything.  If you want to build a matrix row by row, you need something like

```
resampled_ests <- rbind(resampled_ests, rowx)
```

This also means you need to initialize `resampled_ests` before the loop.

Which, if you're doing that anyway, I might just make a 1000 x 2 matrix of zeros and fill in the rows in the loop.  Something like...

```
resampled_ests <- matrix(rep(0, 2*B), nrow=B)
for (b in 1:B) {
ds <- diamonds[resampled_values[b,],]
lm2 <- lm(ds$price~ds$carat, data = ds)
rowx <- coefficients(lm2)
resampled_ests[b,] <- rowx
}
```